# cancel CallableStatement from pool

Tags: java, oracle, callable-statement

in my app (report generator) i run stored procedure with `CallableStatement preparedStatement= connection.prepareCall(sql)`.

inside start execution of sp, i create Request record in db for that.(`DownloadRequest.class`).

in my case sometimes user need to cancel `CallableStatement` from app and oracle. for doing that i create List of `CallableStatement` but i don't know how can i persist id of `CallableStatement` in `DownloadRequest` class. and when user click on cancel button, system cancel sp automatically.

my code:

```
@Component
public class MyComponent{

  private List<CallableStatement> statements = new ArrayList<>();

  public void addStatement(CallableStatement st) {
     statements.add(st);
  }

  public void cancelCallableStatement(DownloadRequest req) throws SQLException {

    Object stId = req.getCallableStatmentIdentifier();

    final Optional<CallableStatement> statement = 
              list.stream().filter(st -> ...... ).findFirst();
    if (statement.isPresent()) {
        final CallableStatement forCancel = statement.get();
        forCancel.cancel();
        statements .remove(forCancel);
    }
  }
}
```

how can save `CallableStatement` identifier in `DownloadRequest` and filter statements according to it?

Comment: i save callableStatement refrence with calling `.toString()` and check with this string.

Comment: Do you really need to cancel it "sometimes" like on demand? There is setQueryTimeout parameter, which allows you to cancel the statement after some time. Also since 18c there is command `ALTER SYSTEM CANCEL SQL` which allows you to interrupt Statement from another session.

Comment: @ibre5041  thank you. i  know about `setQueryTimeout` method. it's for expiration but i need cancel it on demand like you say. can you explain more about this script? `ALTER SYSTEM CANCEL SQL`

Comment: It is a new 18c feature:: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/admin/managing-processes.html#GUID-3FB00298-3914-4D01-A634-DD815E1FE1AB